# Webgrind can see cachegrind file but no output when using ?XDEBUG_PROFILE

Tags: php, debugging, profiling, xdebug, webgrind

When I use `?XDEBUG_PROFILE` in the URL of my script, I get the following in webgrind:

[image]

It appears to detected the cachegrind files but it's not displaying the data.

However, if I turn off `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger` and enable `xdebug.profiler_enable` it works fine.

I really want the functionality of using `?XDEBUG_PROFILE` on demand rather than be profiling all the time.

Anyone knows how to fix it?